# NA's introudced by coercion Classification Tree

Tags: r, statistics, classification

Here's the first few lines of my dataset GF:

```
    GDI LEBF EEF EGIF LFRF MYSF Level
    0.996   83.6    18.2    57140   61.2    12.6    Developed
    0.976   84.5    20.7    33688   58.8    12.9    Developed
    0.950   85.0    15.7    44132   61.8    13.9    Developed
```

I'm trying to create a classification tree for the variable Level as follows:

```
   require(tree)
   GF <- dataset[,c("GDI", "LEBF", "EEF", "EGIF", "LFRF", "MYSF", "Level")]
   tree_f <- tree(formula = Level ~., data = GF)
   plot(tree_f)
   text(tree_f)
```

However, I get the error that NA's are introduced by coercion and I don't understand how so.

Comment: Are the classification outputs numeric or character? Also, do `str(GF)` and see if any of the numbers are actually characters

Comment: The output should be categorical. Doing str(GF), they're all numerical except Level, which is chr

Comment: try making Level a factor and see what hapens?

Comment: okay so that works now, thanks!